# C# async Bitmap resize

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, bitmap

I want to do async task for Bitmap resizing. I thought i would add await to Graphics.DrawImage or Bitmap.Save but i can't. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
    //public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> AddPicture(int? id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPicture(int? id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (extension != ".jpg")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("jpg", "Error");
            }
            else
            {
                // file stream to byte[]
                MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                byte[] TempByteArray = target.ToArray();
                // byte[] to Bitmap
                ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
                Image TempImage = (Image)imageConverter.ConvertFrom(TempByteArray);
                Bitmap FinalBitmap = new Bitmap(TempImage);
                Bitmap Thumbnail = ResizeImage(FinalBitmap, 150, 150);
                Bitmap FullPicture = ResizeImage(FinalBitmap, 800, 600);
                var ThumbnailPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Thumbnails/"), product.ProductCode + ".jpg");
                Thumbnail.Save(ThumbnailPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                var FullPicturePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), product.ProductCode + ".jpg");
                FullPicture.Save(FullPicturePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("missingfile", "Error");
        }
        return View(product);
    }
```

Resize function:

```
    public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
    {
        var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
        destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            double ratioW = (double)width / (double)image.Width;
            double ratioH = (double)height / (double)image.Height;
            double ratio = ratioW < ratioH ? ratioW : ratioH;
            int insideWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
            int insideHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

            using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
            {
                wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                //graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle((width / 2) - (insideWidth / 2), (height / 2) - (insideHeight / 2), insideWidth, insideHeight), 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
            }
        }
        return destImage;
    }
```

Is there anything i can do to make it async?

Thanx

Comment: Wrap it in a `Task`

Comment: But there is nothing in the functon what i could await. I thought i would await graphics.DrawImage but it's void. :(

Comment: You await the Task..

Comment: No need to put await. Task will do the thing you want, async.

Comment: Ok, i will try. Like this: public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height) into **public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Bitmap> ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)**?

Comment: You would want to use `await Task.Run(() =>  ResizeImage…`

Comment: Note that [your controller method needs to be marked as async as well](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#CreatingAsynchGizmos)

Comment: And it will give you no benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like this, see the article below for details:

[Creating an Asynchronous Gizmos Action Method](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GizmosAsync()
{ 
    ViewBag.SyncOrAsync = "Asynchronous";
    var gizmoService = new GizmoService();
    return View("Gizmos", await gizmoService.GetGizmosAsync());
}
```

In order to make something like that work in your case you would need to either wrap your method(s) inside a

```
await Task.Run(()=>{  ... DrawImage() ... })
```

or

you need to use an Async method version instead of your normal sync method for image processing (for example graphics.DrawImageAsync if it exists) - unfortunately I don't believe the *Async version of the method is available so your only option is to spawn a new task (which will run on a thread pool thread).

Your changes would look something like this (I only modified the async/await parts):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddPicture(int? id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    ....
            Bitmap Thumbnail = await ResizeImage(FinalBitmap, 150, 150);
            Bitmap FullPicture = await ResizeImage(FinalBitmap, 800, 600);
    ....
}


public async Task<Bitmap> ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    ....
            await Task.Run(()=>{ graphics.DrawImage(....) });
    ...
```

}